Dialog is not opening as a modal popup - shadcn
In next.js I have added Dialog component from shadcn, but it is not working as a modal or popup.
Screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/fVkQz86t.png
return (
    <Dialog>
        <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline">Open Modal</Button>
        </DialogTrigger>
        <DialogContent className="p-0 bg-transparent border-none max-w-[880px]">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Totam, nobis ad ducimus earum molestiae temporibus, at rerum, ipsam repellat suscipit commodi cum cupiditate repellendus culpa atque. Ut nihil distinctio excepturi!
        </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
);


The code is working for me. Reinstalling the dialog component might help you.

yes @Mridul, after reintalling it is working

@DhavalMakwana I have the same problem atm, what exactly did you do as "reinstalling"?

Make sure you're importing all components from the ui folder. VSCode auto import feature can sometimes import components from the UI folder but also from the RADIX path, which makes the component not work
